# how to get value from the right class if class is included several times

Tags: javascript, html, dom, css-selectors

How do I get the correct value of a class, if the class name is included several times?
I have this structure on a webpage and the value I need is always inside the div "auctionValue" and there in "curreny-coins value" ("5,500" in this example) but this class name ""curreny-coins value" is available 60 times on that page. And I only need the value from "auctionvalue" -> "currency-coins value":

[image]

How can I access this specific class value inside class "auctionValue" and not get all 60 values as a result for example from "auctionStartPrice"?
I tried this:

```
let currencyValues = [];
function highlightDeal() {
    let currentBid = document.getElementsByClassName('currency-coins value');
    for (i = 0; i < currentBid.length; i++) {
        currencyValues.push(currentBid[i].innerHTML);
    }
    console.log(currencyValues);
}

highlightDeal();
```

but it logs an array of all 60 values with that class name.

Comment: You might have a better time with `document.querySelector(".auctionValue .currency-coins.value")`...

Comment: can you provide me the page link?

Comment: @Nikita its within a webapp that needs user login unfortunately

Comment: @AKX same result as for the answer from Manas below

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can target the second child using *nth-child* selector:

```
document.querySelector(".auction > .auctionValue:nth-child(2) > .currency-coins.value")
```

**Demo:**

```js
const bid = document.querySelector(".auction > .auctionValue:nth-child(2) > .currency-coins.value").textContent;

console.log(bid);
```

```html
<div class="auction">

  <div class="auctionValue">
  </div>
  
  <div class="auctionValue">
    <span class="currency-coins value">5,500</span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="auctionValue">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: ok that worked to get the right value. But I need to look at a bigger scope since there are in sum 20 values per page that I need. Each value is nested as follows: 
 li:nth-child(3) > div > div.auction > div:nth-child(2) > span.currency-coins.value
So I have to include li:nth-child(3) where "3" changes on each item (1-20)

Answer (score 0):

**1. Please copy the query selector of the specific element in inspector.**

[image]

**2. And paste it into below code.**

```
const currentBid = document.querySelector("body > main > section > section > div.ut-navigation-container-view--content > div > div > section.ut-pinned-list-container.SearchResults.ui-layout-left > div > ul > li.listFUTItem.has-auction-data.selected > div > div.auction > div:nth-child(2) > span.currency-coins.value").textContent;
console.log(currentBid);
```

Comment: @exec85 does it work?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: currencyValue is not defined
    at highlightDeal (VM7555 deals.js:23)
    at VM8378 deals.js:26

Comment: There wasn't currencyValue in my code. I've updated code.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer from Mamun to get all values on that page:
(example code)

```
function get42() {
    var tds = document.querySelectorAll('td'),
        result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
        result.push(tds[i].textContent);
    }
    return result;
}
```